# Python IDLE Restarting

Tags: python, loops

Recently I have been trying to compute Pi using the Chudnovsky Algorithm. It uses a infinite series so I can't avoid using a infinite loop. At the 487th iteration for i, python just restarts:

```
================= RESTART: Shell =================
```

Here's my code

```
from decimal import *
import sys
import time
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)
  
getcontext().prec = 10000

def factorial(value):
    if value<1:
        return 1
    else:
        return value * factorial(value-1)


print("\nChudnovsky Algorithm Below:")

for i in range(1,1000000):
    pi = 0
    k = 0
    for numoftime in range(0,i):
        pi += (Decimal(-1)**k)*(Decimal(factorial(6*k))/((factorial(k)**3)*(factorial(3*k)))* (13591409+545140134*k)/(640320**(3*k)))
        k += 1
    pi = pi * Decimal(10005).sqrt()/4270934400
    pi = pi**(-1)
    print("Iteration number" ,i, ";" , pi)
```

I'm just wondering if this is my computers fault, or if it is a python bug.

Edit 1:
I also get the same error during the same 487th iteration for a more simple written code:

```
def factorial(value):
if value<1:
    return 1
else:
    return value * factorial(value-1)

for iteration in range(1000):
value1 = ((-1)**iteration)*Decimal(factorial(6*iteration))
```

Not sure if this is helpful but I'm running Python 3.8.6 on a Windows. I'm just using the Editor in python.

Comment: I am running this to see if I get this error

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)` is utterly ludicrous.  That setting has its default value for a *reason*; you might get by with bumping it up a little, but multiplying it by a thousand has no chance of doing anything useful.

Comment: Likewise, calculating `factorial(1000000)` recursively is not going to be viable. Python doesn't do tail-call optimization (and even if it did, your function is not in tail-call form), so you need a while loop.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo. I don't see how I can avoid that. There is no viable formula or equation to rewrite that so that I don't have to write it iteratively.